# Too much notifications for updates in Mint

Tags: linux-mint, notifications

I use Linux Mint. Every 3-5 hours I see a new update notificaton. I have no probelm installing them, but just from curiosity, why do I get them that often? Is it a regular thing? Should I worry about it?

Comment: Updates are for the most part good. You should have settings in update manager on notifications. I do not have mint so I can not write a proper answer, - but should (hopefully) be settings like: How often to check, How often to display nofications, how to handle regular vs security updates etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mintupdate` refresh the `apt` cache periodically and display the available packages upgrade, that's why you get a notification every 3-5 hours (the default is 2 hours, you can adjust it from the `mintupdate` preferences). It is a good feature to keep the system up-to-date.

When you receive a notification, you can upgrade your packages, by executing the following command (without executing `sudo apt update` because it is already done by `mintupdate` ):

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

or

```
sudo mintupdate-cli upgrade
```

See: `man mintupdate`

[Linux Mint Update Manager explained](https://sites.google.com/site/easytipsforlinux/linux-mint-update-manager-explained)

Comment: Does it not distinguish between security updates and regular updates? IMO security updates should be applied when they come (as soon as possible), Other updates can be bundled in a daily at most update. 3-5h update one every little tweak in a release sounds excessive.

Comment: @ibuprofen by default the automatic upgrade is disabled, it can be enabled in the preferences. It will apply all the available updates including the security updates.

Comment: Hmm. OK. In Ubuntu one have «Software Updater» where the GUI has options as: Automatically check for updates: *Daily, Every two days, Every week*, etc. For security updates one have: *Display immediately, Download Automatically, Install Automatically*, For other updates: *Display immediately, Display daily, Display weekly* - But mint does perhaps not have that kind of granularity.

Comment: @ibuprofen i think that the updates have several importance levels ... i remember this from 8 years ago, so i could be wrong

Comment: Some users recommend to use Mint GUI update manager or `mintupdate-cli` instead of  `apt` .
   
`apt` apparently updates && upgrades in very simplified manner, relies mostly on ubuntu / mint devs not messing up, doesn't clean automatically unneeded dependencies, doesn't .   
  
I'd go with `aptitude` or `mintupdate-cli` on Linux mint. It is bit more clever.  Cleans after itself, etc.